# How to show OpenCart Parent Categories to Twitter Bootstrap DropDown Main Nav Menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, opencart

How to show the OpenCart Parent Categories to a Twitter Bootstraped  Navbar Links?

I want to display the Parent Categories only, and here is my HTML Markup

```
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
    <li class="dropdown" id="fat-menu">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="drop3" href="#">Store<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul aria-labelledby="drop3" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Shop Front</a></li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Parent Category 1</a></li><!-- Show Parent Category Here -->
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Parent Category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

AND The current markup and PHP codes that I'm looking into... I've tried to copy the LI But it gives a parse error.

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu-holder" class="<?php echo (isset($styler['menu_style']) && ($styler['menu_style']!='')) ? $styler['menu_style']."_menu" : '' ;?>">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><span class='home_icon'></span></a>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><?php if ($category['children']) { ?><span></span><?php } ?></a>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
            <ul>
                <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
                <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
                <li><a<?php echo ($i==(count($category['children'])-1) ? " class='last_submenu_item'" : '');?> href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is this - `<?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>` ?

Comment: OT: did you put the `role=presentation` in or is that taken from somewhere?

Comment: @B-and-P, that code block was taken from another theme, for comparison purposes.

Comment: @Ryan B, it was taken from TwitterBootstrap's Drop Down Navigation Menu Markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Here's how I did it anyway.

I've put the php code block in an li like this...

```
    <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" ><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li><?php } ?><?php } ?>
```